# Find default browser Windows 8.1 programmatically

Tags: windows, browser, registry

I am trying to find a way to see what is the default browser of machine (Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 specifically) programtically.

Is there a registry key that holds the value of what is default browser?

Comment: You can't ask for programmatic solution without mentioning any specific language. See this question on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/436939/where-is-the-default-program-associations-stored-in-the-registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the registry key
`Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice`

It will list what is the default browser for HTTP protocal. Likewise, you can check for HTTPS, HTMl and such.

Good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You should read

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
```

If user didn't change default browser away from IE, this registry key under HKEY_CURRENT_USER won't exist. So, check HKEY_CURRENT_USER first. If not such key/value, check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE as fallback.

If the value isn't `IEXPLORE.EXE`, the default browser isn't IE.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396